# where to look up newtonsoft json.net breaking changes?

Tags: json.net

I have a bunch of code I'd like to upgrade from using 
JSON.net 4.0.3 to 4.5.8 or whatever is latest.  Are there any known 
breaking changes, or a place I can look to find them? 
  I saw this: http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22498 which looks to 
be fixed in 4.5.3.  I saw this as well: 
http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/03/20/json-net-4-5-release-1-iso-dates-async-metro-build.aspx, which I might need to address.

Answer (score 17):

Releases from 6.0.4 forward have [release notes on the GitHub repository for the project.](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases)

Answer (score 3):

All the releases have their changes listed on the blog you link to ( http://james.newtonking.com/ ) and on the [particular article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/03/20/json-net-4-5-release-1-iso-dates-async-metro-build.aspx) he says that the package will now only make breaking change on major version number changes (semantic versioning, hurrah!).

So by trawling the blog for each post relating to a major version change (i.e. 6.0.0) you can work out what changes you need to worry about. I have not seen a better compiled list.